# Different C compilers giving different results for Merge Sort

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I am running a merge sort implementation and it is giving correct results in https://code.hackerearth.com/4a1c9cn but wrong results in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php.

Can somebody tell me the mistakes and the things to keep in mind to avoid such mistakes in the future.
Sample test case: 5 3 7 5 9 2
Wrong answer by the second compiler: 03579
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int A[], int left[], int right[], int n)
{
     int i=0, j=0, k=0, m = n/2, d = n-m;
     while(i<m && j<d)
     {
         if(left[i] <= right[j]) A[k++] = left[i++];
         else A[k++] = right[j++];
     }
    if(i == m)
        for(;k<n; k++, j++) A[k] = right[j];
    else if(j == d)
        for(; k<n; k++, i++) A[k] = left[i];
    return;
}

void MergeSort(int A[], int n)
{
    if(n==1) return;
    int m = n/2;
    int* left = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    int* right = (int*)malloc((n-m)*sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) left[i] = A[i];
    for(i=m; i<n; i++, j++) right[j] = A[i];
    MergeSort(left, m);
    MergeSort(right, (n-m));
    merge(A, left, right, n);
    return;
} 

int PrintArr(int A[], int n);
void getArr (int A[], int n);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n, *arr;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    getArr(arr, n);
    MergeSort(arr, n);
    PrintArr(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are not going to click these links. The title suggests that your code is invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Things to keep in mind: avoid undefined behaviors, and exercise great caution with implementation-defined ones.  If you have questions about the specifics of your code, however, then the code needs to appear *in the question*.

Comment: Hi.  I have added the code for clarity.

Comment: It is leaking memory like crazy... All of these mallocs are totally unnecessary. The sorting can be done in-place.

Comment: `int i, j;` --> `int i, j = 0;` : (Using uninitialized variable `j` at `right[j] = A[i];`)

Comment: Or instead, assign `j = 0` in the corresponding `for` loop. The assignment to `i`, there is superfluous, anyhow.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree that it is leaking memory, but can you elaborate on how to merge sort in place? AFAIK merge sort is not an in place sort.

Comment: Perhaps the "in-place" was misleading statement. It is not in-place. What I meant that it can be done with a statically allocated storage of the same size as the source array (a destination buffer?), or dynamically allocated just once.

Comment: Thanks.  I followed the advice. And fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After helpful comments, I was able to fix the code.  The reason of the error was memory leaking.  Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int A[], int l, int h)
{   int* temp = (int*)malloc((h-l+1)*sizeof(int));
    int i=l, k=0, m = l + (h-l)/2, j = m+1;
    while(i<=m && j<=h)
    {
        if(A[i] <= A[j]) temp[k++] = A[i++];
        else temp[k++] = A[j++];
    }
    if(i > m)
        for(;k<=h; k++, j++) temp[k] = A[j];
    else if(j > h)
        for(; k<=h; k++, i++) temp[k] = A[i];
    for(i=l, k=0; i<=h; i++,k++) A[i] = temp[k];
    return;
}

void MergeSort(int A[], int l, int h)
{
   if(h-l<1) return;
   int m = l + (h-l)/2;
   MergeSort(A, l, m);
   MergeSort(A, m+1, h);
   merge(A, l, h);
   return;
}


int PrintArr(int A[], int n)

void getArr (int A[], int n)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     int n, *arr;
    scanf("%d", &n);
   arr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   getArr(arr, n);
   MergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);
   PrintArr(arr, n);
   return 0;
}
```